# Php json_encode data request

Tags: php, mysql, json

I get data from my sql query, then i try to json_encode these data, but that return me a false

```
    $response = array();
    $request = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM mytest");
    while ($row = $request->fetch_array()){
        $response[] = $row;
    }
    var_dump($response);
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

my echo is empty cause that return false, and my var_dump($response) return me :

```
array (size=12)
  0 => 
    array (size=8)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string 'b�lier' (length=6)
      'sign' => string 'b�lier' (length=6)
      2 => string 'description du b�lier' (length=21)
      'description' => string 'description du b�lier' (length=21)
      3 => string '2021-05-22' (length=10)
      'date' => string '2021-05-22' (length=10)
  1 => 
    array (size=8)
      0 => string '2' (length=1)
      'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      1 => string 'taureau' (length=7)
      'sign' => string 'taureau' (length=7)
      2 => string 'description du taureau' (length=21)
      'description' => string 'description du taureau' (length=21)
      3 => string '2021-05-22' (length=10)
      'date' => string '2021-05-22' (length=10)
```

Comment: Why the `while` loop when you can just use `json_encode($request->fetch_array())` ?

Comment: I have try like this, but i have the same problem, json_encode($request->fetch_array() return me false too

Comment: That wouldn't change anything, I was only asking what you think the additional `while` loop is actually achieving here? Also, have you checked what [`json_last_error`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) gives you yet?

Comment: Oh i didn't know last error, that was malformated utf-8 characters in my database, so its resolved, thanks for your help

Comment: No problem. Glad its resolved. Consider adding an answer to help future viewers with similar problems. Also, the `while` loop is redundant here - you can use `$response = $request->fetch_array()` or just `json_encode()` it directly.